# Running sencha app watch locally on sambashare

Tags: linux, samba

I have setup a vm on my small NAS, that is functioning as a apache web server. I've installed sencha, Sencha Cmd and yii2. Everything was working okay, but as it turns out my NAS is a little to old/slow to handle the app watcher from Sencha Cmd. So I've installed Sencha Cmd locally on my Mac and created a network share through samba on my web server where the sencha app is. The problem is, when I navigate to the samba share on my Mac and try to launch `sencha app watch -w false` there, I am getting an error:

```
 [ERR]      [echo] App watch is already running for this build profile.
```

On my web server sencha app watch isn't running anymore, so I don't really understand the problem here. Anyone here tried something similar like me? (Running sencha app watch locally on a network share) Is there something I need to do first, to make it run? Like specifying the network path somewhere? Unfortunately I couldn't find any documantation on this topic anywhere.
My web server is running on Ubuntu.
Sencha Cmd version: 7.7.0.36

I've tried looking for a solution online, but couldn't find anything. I suspect it has something to do with the samba share configuration.